# Overriding isEqual: so that different objects can equal the same object (sort of)

Tags: objective-c

So I have a situation where im using a class as a kind of struct. now i want to override the `isEqual:` method so if this type of object is inside an array, i can use `[objects indexOfObject:obj]`

but, now say `obj` contains objects called duck, and chicken, i would like to go `[objects indexOfObject:duck]` and it will actually give me the index of `obj`

so i tried something like this:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject {

    if([anObject isKindOfClass:[Duck class]]){

        return [anObject isEqual:_duck];
    }
    else if([anObject isKindOfClass:[Chicken class]]){

        return [anObject isEqual:_chicken];
    }

    return [anObject isEqual:self];
}
```

which doesnt work and isnt even getting called... think that has to do with overriding hash, which i tried by just returning self.hash (effectively obj.hash) but that didnt work.

Do you think something like this is possible? or should i just use for loops to search through all my `obj`'s to find which duck is contained in which `obj` and return the index of it (which i can do, just wanted to try be cool and neat at the same time)

Comment: could you please show more code? how do you fill objects array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds using `-isEqual:` is a bad idea here.

You can't have a DuckAndChicken that compares equal to its Duck and its Chicken, (and vice versa) because in order to stay consistent, all ducks and chickens would then have to compare equal.

Example:

1. duck1 + chicken1 compares equal to duck1
2. chicken1 compares equal to duck1 + chicken1
3. duck2 + chicken1 compares equal to chicken1
4. duck2 compares equal to duck1
5. Universe explodes

The good news is that you don't have to use `-indexObject:` to retrieve from the array. NSArray has a handy `-indexOfObjectPassingTest:` method that should do what you want.

```
        [ducksAndChickens indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(DuckAndChicken *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([obj.duck isEqual:myDuck]) {
                // woop woop...
            }
        }];
```

Comment: this sounds like a very good alternative to what im looking for, can just define the block somewhere once then use it multiple times, keeping it a one liner which will be neat

Comment: Yeah, a category on NSArray sounds like overkill for something so simple. @NathanDay's suggestion will likely perform better if you have a lot of objects though.

Comment: nah its not really overkill, its a very short category to write for what im trying to do so not really a hassle. if this answer was suggested before i made the category i probably would have used it, but done the category and implemented it so dont really feel like reverting. i wish i could mark both as the answer, but ill mark this as the answer because it would have been better/easier for my purposes than a category, even though i used the other answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it sounds like a hash issue.

I would avoid trying to do this by overriding `isEqual:` because you're liable to break things that you don't think you'd break.

Instead add a custom method that you can call to determine your version of equivalence. Then have a helper method or a category on `NSArray` which adds `my_indexOfObject:` and does the iteration.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with overriding `isEqual:` as long as it uses `super` object's invocation.

Comment: determining the hash is still going to be a problem though, since the hash function doesnt really know about if you are comparing a duck or a chicken

Comment: @kovpas, `isEqual:` and `hash` are like a pair, if you override one you need to override the other to 'match'. It isn't necessarily a problem, but it can be complicated and if you do a bad job you can ruin at least the performance of collections and potentially the operation of them all together.

Comment: @Fonix, just add your own methods, don't override `isEqual:` or `hash`. The complexity of the `hash` you'd need to write (or the triviality of the response it would need to give) is exactly the reason to not try...

Comment: @Wain agreed, ill try adding a category to NSMutableArray

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell what you really want to do from your example but could you perhaps have two dictionaries one where ducks are the key and one where chickens are the key and the object value is either the actual parent object or a NSNumber with the index in the array. This would make lookup much quicker though would take up more memory, and could make synchronisation between the three data structs.

Comment: the first line of my question is all i want, nothing complicated, just want my code to be neater (at the moment i have multiple arrays of ducks and chickens and keeping the ducks and chickens associated is becoming quite a hassel, hence why i want them in a 'struct' and just able to index them in one array). This could work as well if i dont get the category suggestion right